# Which functions are $C^k$, but not $C^{k+1}$ on $ \mathbb{R} $

Tags: calculus, continuity

The only functions I can think of that fulfill this property are the polynomials of degree k.

However this does not necessarily imply, that this are the only functions that are in such a space. So I am curious, if there exist some further characterization of this set.

So I would be very happy about any constructive comment, answer or recommendation for further reading. As always thanks in advance.

Comment: Polynomials of degree $k$ are $C^\infty$. They have $n$th order derivative $0$ for all $n > k$ though. A product of a smooth function and the Weierstrass function is again nowhere differentiable.

Comment: @EricThoma, oh, interesting. Then I am sorry for jumping to conclusions.

Comment: Maybe I should concreitze, the function's k'th derivative is not equal 0.

Comment: If a function's $k$th derivative is identically $0$, then the function will be a polynomial, recovered by integration. I think the question as initially asked is compelling.

Comment: Perhaps an obstacle for a satisfying answer: "most" functions that are $C^k$ are not $C^{k+1}$. We can give certain properties of functions in this set, but our classifications must be limited in specificity to statements that apply to most $C^k$ functions.

Comment: the best example is $\displaystyle f(x) = |x|^{k+1-\epsilon}$ where $\epsilon \in [0;1[$.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a lot of these by taking a discontinuous function and then integrating it. For example, if we take the Heaviside function
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x \leq 0\\
1 & x > 0
\end{cases}
$$
then
$$
h(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)~dt = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x \leq 0\\
x & x \geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
and 
$$
g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x h(t)~dt = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x \leq 0\\
x^2 & x \geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
give us a function $g\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ (since $g' = h$, and $h$ is continuous) but $g\notin C^2(\mathbb{R})$ (since $g' = h$ is not differentiable near 0).

Answer (score 2):

Most (in the sense of Baire category) continuous functions are nowhere differentiable. See [Most Continuous Functions are Nowhere Differentiable](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math414/fs.pdf).

Given any continuous nowhere differentiable function ($C^0$ and not $C^1$), any primitive will be $C^1$ but not $C^2$...